# Processing network calls from background. Is it allowed by Apple?

Tags: ios, objective-c

We are working in a groupon-like app where alerts are displayed to the user when he/she enters in the range of an offer.

The client insists on having alerts even when the app is in the background.

Due to the architecture of the system, the app gets the location of the client at intervals and checks with the server if there is any new alert. If so, the app does some processing in the local database and displays a notification.

APN cannot be used since changes in the server are out of reach for this project.

My question is whether Apple would accept it in AppleStore as I have read different opinions about it and Apple discourages its use as in this extract from iOS Developer Library

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html

> At wake-up time, your app is put into the background and given a small amount of time to process the location data. Because your app is in the background, it should do minimal work and avoid any tasks (such as querying the network) that might prevent it from returning before the allocated time expires. If it does not, your app may be terminated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should reconsider your approach for this application. It sounds like you have decided to build a set of features which are not necessarily well informed by, or a good fit for, the characteristics of the devices the app will run on.

You write that "the app gets the location every n minutes" but that's not how iOS location services work. Querying location services for the current location occasionally is a good approach when your app is running in the foreground but that's not an option once it is suspended or terminated. Instead you need to subscribe to location events, at some level of accuracy, and your app will be notified when the device's location changes. There are no guarantees about the schedule on which you receive these events and it varies depending on the accuracy you request and the speed at which the device is moving.

Additionally, obtaining a location is an expensive operation and can quickly drain the device's battery. Burning through a user's available battery power in an hour or two is a very good way to get your app uninstalled quickly. Where possible you should be using the significant location change service to get low accuracy location updates with minimal power consumption. If you need more precision then consider using boundary crossing events for a defined region or at least reduce the accuracy your have requested as much as possible.

With all that out of the way you still need to work within the limited time your app has to run once started by a location update. That's probably not long enough to make a round trip to the server. If a network connection is already active and the device happens to have low latency you will probably get a response some of the time but I would expect to see the app terminated by the OS frequently. When that happens I don't know that you will continue to receive location updates which might otherwise re-launch the app.

Instead of downloading a list of alerts and displaying them locally a better solution might be to attempt to send your current location to the server via UDP when you see a significant location change. That way you can fire off a network request without waiting for a response. Only some of those requests will still succeed but at least your app won't be terminated. You can then process the locations you receive on the server and send push notifications when appropriate.

I realize that you don't seem to be able to make server side changes. In that case the best you might be able to do is pre-fetch alerts for the nearby region when the app runs (and if you ever manage to complete a round-trip while in the background). That way you could compare location updates to that list and not need to fire off a network request on every location update. Unfortunately it sounds like you might be backed into a corner here with no reliable solution available under your current constraints.

Comment: Thanks, Jonah and @yeesterbunny. I think now I can come back to the client with a better understanding of the issue.

Answer (score 2):

How often does your app get location from the user? According to Apple's [Background Execution and Multitasking](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html), if you are getting the location updates on a regular schedule (I think it's less than 10 minutes), your app can still process in the background if you add `location` to `UIBackgroundModes` in your `info.plist`. With those `CLLocation` coordinates, you can then process your web service requests.

I personally have not done something like this, so I can't tell you for sure if Apple will reject your app or not. However, if everything is within the guideline and requirements set by Apple, I don't see why they would reject your app.

**EDIT**:

**From the Apple doc:**

> An app that provides continuous location updates to the user (even
>   when in the background) can enable background location services by
>   including the UIBackgroundModes key (with the location value) in its
>   Info.plist file. The inclusion of this value in the UIBackgroundModes
>   key does not preclude the system from suspending the app, but it does
>   tell the system that it should wake up the app whenever there is new
>   location data to deliver. Thus, this key effectively lets the app run
>   in the background to process location updates whenever they occur.

I guess even if the app is suspended, it will wake up whenever there is a new location data to deliver.

Comment: The app gets the location every n minutes where n is defined by a parameter sent from the server. Normally this is done every five minutes but it can be changed dynamically.

Comment: I've edited my answer. According to the Apple doc, even if your app is suspended, it will wake up when there is new location data available.